# How to call the following command using subprocess in python " python -m xport C:/abc.xpt > C:/abc.csv "

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-3.5

How to call the following command using subprocess in python **" python -m xport C:/abc.xpt > C:/abc.csv "**?

The command works properly in command prompt.
But gives an error when tried to execute via subprocess in python.

**subprocess.call(["python", "-m", "xport", "C:/abc.xpt" , ">" , "C:/abc.csv"])**

The above command gives an error saying,
**usage: xport.py [-h] [input]
xport.py: error: unrecognized arguments: C:/abc.csv**

Comment: Why use subprocess, since you're just calling another Pythons script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`> C:/abc.csv` is a redirect of the output to a text file and not part of the command.
But if you are inside a python script already, why don't you call the function or module directly? There is no need to use a subprocess, but if you want to use it you need to catch the output and store it somewhere (in a variable or file)

```
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> output = proc.stdout.read()
>>> print output
bar
baz
foo
```